# How can I repair a plastic dowel in a cabinet

Tags: doors

How can I repair a plastic dowel in a cabinet in which the hole is compromised as in the picture pls.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use an appropriately sized plastic wall anchor, cut down to match the depth of the hole:

[image]

Instead of the large fastener designed for the original plastic plug, use a short self-tapping sheet metal screw, as large as will fit the hole in the hinge base. Put wood glue in the hole prior to inserting the anchor and screwing it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Does the dowel have pressure on it? IE do you pull or push something? You could put in a larger piece of PVC pipe to fit the hole snugly, then use the original size dowel inside that pipe. Maybe use gorilla glue for plastic (looks like gorilla wood glue was used once) or another type of plastic cement/epoxy.